# SQL Server: subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL statement that looks for a certain word between a keyword and a blank space. The query also tells me whether or not the keyword is present in the data. When I run the query, I get the error message about the subquery returning more than 1 value and I understand the error. But I'm not sure how to fix the error.

So I tried the following.

If I run the subquery like this, I do not get any error.

```
select t.IncidentId, LEFT(tt.CadRemarks, charindex(' ', tt.CadRemarks) - 1) 
as callType
from IncidentMisc t cross apply 
 ( values (substring(CadRemarks, charindex('dispatch level: ', CadRemarks) + 
16, len(CadRemarks))) 
 ) tt(CadRemarks)
 where t.CadRemarks like '%dispatch level: %'
```

But when I run this, I get the error.

```
select incidentid,
case 
when CadRemarks like '%dispatch level:%'
then (
select LEFT(tt.CadRemarks, charindex(' ', tt.CadRemarks) - 1) 
as callType
from IncidentMisc t cross apply 
 ( values (substring(CadRemarks, charindex('dispatch level: ', CadRemarks) + 
16, len(CadRemarks))) 
 ) tt(CadRemarks)
 --where t.CadRemarks like '%dispatch level: %'
 )
else ''
end as CallType
from IncidentMisc
```

Desired Output example.

```
incidentid      callType
-------------------------
_170039075
_170039076
_170039077
_1700501046      52B01
_1700501048      17B01
_1700501049      67C01
```

It looks like I am going to have to take a different approach. This question can be closed.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: *"but I'm not sure how to fix the error"* make the subquery return 1 or 0 rows.

Comment: @larnu - updated the question.

Comment: "*If I run the subquery like this, I do not get any error"* Because it's not a subquery. A **subquery** cannot return more than 1 row. I bet that query returns 2+ rows (we don't have any sample data to test). You say you understand the error, but it seems you don't. it's telling you exactly what the problem is though. When you have a subquery that is being used to return a **scalar** value (like you have here) it must return no more than 1 rows.

Comment: @Larnu - yeah. I thought I did, but I do not. I've added the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT incidentid,
       CASE
           WHEN CadRemarks LIKE '%dispatch level:%'
           THEN
(
    SELECT top 1 (LEFT(tt.CadRemarks, CHARINDEX(' ', tt.CadRemarks) - 1))
    FROM IncidentMisc t
         CROSS APPLY(VALUES(SUBSTRING(CadRemarks, CHARINDEX('dispatch level: ', CadRemarks) + 16, LEN(CadRemarks)))) tt(CadRemarks)
)
           ELSE ''
       END AS CallType
FROM IncidentMisc;
```

this should work, but if you clarify more I can check whether this suits all your scenarios.

Comment: Thanks, but this returns same callType value for all incidentid. The callType are different, too.